# Refer to Parent selector using 'this' in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, this

I have a following jQuery code which validates user name of my registration form using `$.post`

```
$("input[name='username']").blur(function() {
    $("#usernm").html("<img src='css/assets/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading'/>");
    $.post("validate.jsp", {
        fieldtype : $(this).attr("name"),
        fieldval : $(this).val()
    },
    function(resp) {
        if(resp.trim()!="true")
            $("input[name='username']").addClass("invalidvalue");
        else
            $("input[name='username']").removeClass("invalidvalue");
        $("#usernm").html("&nbsp;");
    })
});
```

And currently I have such method blocks for each input on my form that I'm validating, What I want to do is instead of using `$("input[name='username']").addClass("invalidvalue");` I want to use something like `$(this)` such that it points to the `input[name='username']` also I want to keep only single method for each input that I want to validate so that I can reduce my JS code.

How to work out that?

Comment: if you have a username it think there will be a password two. Do you have 2 fields like "repeat password" ? for such a situation i have to adopt my answer

Comment: @Neysor: yes I do have another field for confirm password, but only first input of password is posted to server for validation, for confirm password input, I match it with first password input at the client end itself.

Answer (score 1):

For validating all input fields , you could use something like this:

```
//Mapping of input elements and its 'loading' elements 
var inputMap = { 'username' : 'usernm' };

$("input").blur(function() {
   var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
   var that = this;

   $( "#"+inputMap[inputName] ).html("<img src='css/assets/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading'/>");       
   $.post("validate.jsp", {
       fieldtype : inputName,
       fieldval : $(this).val()
   },
   function(resp) {
       if(resp.trim()!="true")
           $(that).addClass("invalidvalue");
       else
           $(that).removeClass("invalidvalue");
       $("#"+inputMap[inputName]).html("&nbsp;");
   })
});
```

Comment: @Engineer Nice solution but I think a class based selection is better then an id one... because you have to build an input map before. And classes make "marks" in the HTML and do not need an map :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done with setting a class on the elements you want to have with this function.

Make your input fields like that:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="validate">
<input type="password" name="password" class="validate">
```

The jQuery Code

```
$(".validate").each(function(){
  $(this).blur(function(){
    var field = $(this);
    field.addClass("loading"); //Make a class for loading behavior if possible
    $.post(
      "validate.jsp",
      {  fieldtype:field.attr("name"),
         fieldval :field.val()
      },
      function(resp) {
        field.removeClass("loading"); //see on top
        if(resp.trim()!="true") {
          field.addClass("invalidvalue");
        }
        else {
          field.removeClass("invalidvalue");
        }
      }
   });
});
```

If you want to have some special variables for some fields you can use the HTML data-* types and make something like this:

```
<input name="username" class="validate" data-var="blabla">
```

and you can use the value then with `field.attr("data-var");`